# How to build screen saver in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, osx-mountain-lion, screensaver

I'm making an OSX screen saver in Xcode (Objective-C, ScreenSaverView class, etc.), and it runs within Xcode correctly. When I navigate to the build output folder and double-click on the the `.saver` file, it opens System Preferences/Desktop & Screen Saver and asks if I want to install it. All correct.

But when I email the `.saver` file to myself and open it, System Preferences opens but not to Desktop & Screen Saver and no option to install it is presented. I think it may have to do with the fact that when I build it (with, as far as I can tell, build settings specifying "Release" instead of "Debug"), the output file is still in `/Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ScreenSaver/Build/Products/Debug/` rather than a release folder.

What am I missing here? I have very little experience with configuring build settings, compiler flags, etc.

---

**Edit:**

For what it's worth, it seems to work if I compress the output `.saver` file as a `.zip` and email that instead. Not a great solution though.

Comment: It sounds like it's being built fine. Email will mess up binary attachments so you need to encode it some way, such as zipping it, or [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) encoding it. That's pretty typical of anything other than text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comment above, apparently it's being built correctly; email messes up binary file attachments so to have it work correctly it should be encoded (e.g. by zipping it) before attaching.